# Something's missing from my Unattended XML

Tags: xml, sysprep, unattend-file

I'm using this brief unattended.xml file ive written to be used with sysprep, and although the basics are quite obvious, i think there's an issue with either the layout, headings, or maybe even the settings pass, anyone have any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State">         
            <OOBE> 
                <InputLocale>0452:00000452</InputLocale>
                <SystemLocale>en-GB</SystemLocale>
                <UILanguage>en-GB</UILanguage>
                <UserLocale>en-GB</UserLocale>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <NetworkLocation>Other</NetworkLocation> 
                <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
                <TimeZone>GMT Standard Time</TimeZone>
                <SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE> 
            </OOBE>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever views this I sorted it. There were tonnes of problems with stuff being set at the wrong pass and such. I just went back and did the whole thing from scratch using Windows System Image Manager.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is that your code for GB (UK) is not correct:

```
<InputLocale>0452:00000452</InputLocale>
```

It should be `0809:00000809` and hence the correct element would be

```
<InputLocale>0809:00000809<InputLocale>
```

Also, if you're getting the specialized missing error, it may be that the GMT Standard Time in TimeZone should be in the specialized area with shell setup underneath.